# Azure : Unable to view custom logs generated by application

Tags: python, azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I'm running my flask application container on Azure. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#instrument-with-opencensus-python-sdk-with-azure-monitor-exporters) tutorial, I configured logging in my application. But it's not stated as to where to view these logs in Azure. Please help.

Comment: Please refer [Confirm data is flowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=python#confirm-data-is-flowing)

Comment: no I do not see any requests in the charts on Azure Monitor

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT I have followed the opencensus tutorial provided by Azure. I do not see any data flowing like you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Insights and solutions provide a custom experience for working with data stored in Azure Monitor. You can work directly with log data using a log query written in Kusto Query Language (KQL). In the Azure portal, you can write and run queries and interactively analyze data using Log Analytics. Analyze metrics in the Azure portal with the Metrics Explorer. See Analyze log data in [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview#where-to-see-application-insights-data) and Getting started with [Azure Metrics Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-getting-started).

Comment: My only requirement is to be able to write custom logs to Azure which I can use to debug the application at a later point in time.